# How to get hls video width/height in javascript?

Tags: javascript, video, http-live-streaming

I use `video` tag to play HLS video, and the video size is 0 always.

```
<video id=video src="http://xxx.m3u8" autoplay controls/>
<script>
    const video = document.getElementById('video')
    video.addEventListener('play', () => {
        console.log(video.videoWidth, video.videoHeight)
        // both are 0
    })
</script>
```

Comment: have you tried the canplay and canplaythrough events? if the video is not same origin, it may well be that the metadata is not available to you

Comment: @JaromandaX I tried to play a mp4 file from other domain, and then I could read the `videoWidth` and `videoHeight` property correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Currently desktop browsers do **not** support playing an HLS video directly using just the video tag. (Maybe it does work on Safari or IOS).

To reproduce an HLS stream you need to use one of the video players available. You have some open source projects, like hlsjs: https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js. Or comercial players like flowplayer, or jwplayer.

Basic html code using hlsjs player:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hls.js@latest"></script>
<video id="video"></video>
<script>
  if(Hls.isSupported()) {
    var video = document.getElementById('video');
    var hls = new Hls();
    hls.loadSource('https://video-dev.github.io/streams/x36xhzz/x36xhzz.m3u8');
    hls.attachMedia(video);
    hls.on(Hls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED,function() {
      video.play();
  });
 }
</script>
```

Comment: HLS source in the video tag will work directly on Safari (Desktop) as well as iOS and some Android browsers. For other desktop browsers like Chrome or Firefox, hls.js works pretty well as you've mentioned in your answer.

Comment: I just wanna to get the video size, or radio, do not need a player to play it.

Comment: how to know resolution by playing it?

Answer (score 1):

`"loadedmetadata"` **wont' work for HLS streams**, 
so this is the best solution

```
var video = document.getElementById("video")
video.onplaying = function () {
    var width = video.videoWidth
    var height = video.videoHeight
    console.log("video dimens loaded w="+width+" h="+height)
    }
```